# insert values into an array one by one typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to insert values into an array one by one like java or c#.

```
var listOfProduct: IProduct[];
var product = new Array<IProduct>();

product.name= newName;
product.id= newId;
product.price= newPriceAfterDiscount;

this.listofproducts.push(product);
```

but typescript don't support that approach.

if there is another solution or idea for that i will be greatful.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var listOfProduct = [] as IProduct[];
var product = {} as IProduct;

product.name = newName;
product.id = newId;
product.price = newPriceAfterDiscount;

listOfProduct.push(product);
```

Or:

```
var listOfProduct = [] as IProduct[];
listOfProduct.push({
    name: newName,
    id: newId,
    price: newPriceAfterDiscount
});
```